# How do include space in like statement SQL

Tags: sql, string, space

I am wondering how to query any number of characters then a space then any number of characters then a comma?

I am looking for last names in a table that contains a space before the comma. For example, they query would return `SMITH III, Richard`.

Thanks in advance

Comment: And your DB engine is?

Comment: use `like`, `last_name like '% %,'`

Comment: select * from cabinet..users where FullName like '% %,%'
worked

Comment: You should list your solution as an answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

The % symbol is used to denote a wildcard, you can use it like this:

```
SELECT * FROM [myTable] WHERE [myField] LIKE '% %,%'
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server you may find performance better with [PATINDEX](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190184%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

```
SELECT * FROM [myTable] WHERE PATINDEX('% %,%',[myField]) > 0
```